# LabVIEW - How to accumulate data in array?

Tags: logic, labview

I made a program aimed to simulate the intensity of light when many light bulbs are put together. I have intensity data of one bulb in xls.-files. So, I want to program to work as follows.

1. Open the xls.-file and get the data.
2. Put the data into different positions. I put one data set (one bulb) in each excel sheet. This is to simulate putting the bulb in different places.
3. Sum the data in the same cell across the different sheets.

[image: diagram illustrating summation of data]

My LabVIEW front panel and block diagram are:

[image: LabVIEW front panel and block diagram]

My problem is this program runs too slowly. How should I improve this? I have an idea to make a big array and accumulate data in that array. However, I do not know how to do it. The `Insert Into Array` and `Replace Array Subset` functions are not suitable for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable reason of slow performance is that you do a lot of operations on Excel file. You should rather read data into memory and operate on them in VI. At the end, if you need, you can update the Excel file with final results.

It would be difficult to tell you exactly how to do it. As you said, you're beginner and I think that the best way would be to simple do some LabVIEW exercises and gain more experience to understand how to work with arrays :) I recommend to **take a look at examples** (Help->Find Examples), read some user guides from ni.com or find other "getting started" materials on the Internet.

Check these, you may find them useful:

- https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361R-01/lvhowto/lv_getting_started/
- https://www.ni.com/getting-started/labview-basics/data-structures
- https://www.ni.com/pl-pl/support/documentation/supplemental/08/labview-arrays-and-clusters-explained.html

Comment: Thank you so much. I will check those links and let you know more updates soon.